# with union clause i am getting repeating rows how can i solve below example please see and comment?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select  customer_id, null, customer_type
from    customer
where   rownum <=10
union 
select  customer_id, CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE, null
from    customer
where   rownum <=10;
```

I am getting output like below and repeating id.

```
12507000000392     02X8    NULL
12507000000392     NULL    PRES
```

But I want output like this.
Please comment if u know.

```
12507000000392     02X8    PRES
```

Comment: Please share your table structure and existing data in the table. I think use of JOIN will help you.

Comment: Why are you using UNION in the first place? Why not simply: `select  customer_id, CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE, customer_type
    from    customer
    where   rownum <=10`

Comment: I'm with Craig Young here. A customer_id should uniquely identify a record in the customer table of course, so why selecting this record twice, once nulling out one field, once the other, and then saying you want to see the complete record, though. That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Even with Union here You are taking Null as customer_sub_type and null as customer type. 
Here there is not duplicate rows returning by Query. So in this case Union will not be helpful.
Still you can try with following Query.

SELECT CUSTOMER_ID , MAX(CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE) , MAX(CUSTOMER_TYPE)
 FROM CUSTOMER
 GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Why not just `select customer_ID, customer_Sub_Type, customer_Type from customer where rowNum<=10`